# How to programmatically set twig block content?

Tags: php, twig

Is it possible to set the value of a twig template block from PHP code? I'm migrating from a different template engine and I need a bridge to set the value of blocks without using a twig template.

I've just got plain text that I was hoping to assign before I render the template.

Comment: Could you point out an example with some code perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include PHP files inside blocks, I suggest you to create an extension.

### Sample

<kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
<?php

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array());

$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_php_contents', function($file, $context) {
    ob_start();
    include($file); // $context is available in your php file
    return ob_get_clean();
}, array('is_safe' => array('html')));

$twig->addFunction($function);

echo $twig->render('test.twig', array('name' => 'Alain'));
```

<kbd>test.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{{ get_php_contents('contents.php', _context) }}
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>base.twig</kbd>

```
<html>
    <div>I'm a base layout</div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</html>
```

<kbd>contents.php</kbd>

```
<?php

echo '<div style="color:red">';
echo "Hello {$context['name']}, it is now: ";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo '</div>';
```

### Result

```
<html>
    <div>I'm a base layout</div>
    <div style="color:red">Hello Alain, it is now: 2014-10-28 19:23:23</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As is implied by the accepted answer, the blunt answer to the question as posted is "You can't." The Twig API has nothing to offer here.

The other answer's Twig extension to directly render PHP files in Twig might be intuitive for some use cases, but it wasn't for mine. I wanted to do everything in a single PHP file that grabbed various Twig templates and sent data among them. The more reasonable answer for me was to make my PHP file only have to render a single Twig file at all, rather than having a Twig file grab and run my PHP. I had basically this:

<kbd>card-list.twig</kbd> (parent component)

```
{{ top_level_stuff }}

{% block the_cards_i_want_to_override %}
  {% for item in items %}
    {{ include('single-card.twig') }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>single-card.twig</kbd> (sub-component)

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div>{{ content }}</div>
```

<kbd>card-from-post.twig</kbd> (mapping from one content type to its card)

```
{{ include(
  'single-card.twig',
  {
    title: post.post_title,
    content: post.summary
  }
) }}
```

What I (thought I) wanted to do was this:

<kbd>card-list-from-posts.php</kbd> (can't work this way)

```php
$block_content = '';

// Loop over blog posts and provide them to my mapping template to build the content for the block override.
foreach($posts as $post) {
  // The following function doesn't exist; it's a placeholder for whatever your Twig environment would call for.
  $block_content .= render_twig_template_normally( 
    'card-from-post.twig',
    [ 'post' => $post ]
  );
}

// The following function also does not exist; it's a placeholder for what I wish existed, but does not in any form.
render_twig_template_with_block_override( 
  'card-list.twig',
  [ 'top_level_stuff' => 'whatever' ],
  [ 'the_cards_i_want_to_override' => $block_content ]
);
```

What I actually had to do in the end was create one more Twig file like this:

<kbd>card-list-from-posts.twig</kbd>

```
{% embed 'card-list.twig' with {
  top_level_stuff: top_level_stuff
} %}
  {% block the_cards_i_want_to_override %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      {{ include('card-from-post.twig') }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

...and then change my PHP to this:

<kbd>card-list-from-posts.php</kbd> (does work)

```php
render_twig_template_normally(
  'card-list-from-posts.twig',
  [
    'top_level_stuff' =>'whatever',
    'posts' => $posts,
  ]
);
```